# AWS Load Balancing & Auto Scaling test

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-testing

Recently we moved our java web appication to beanstalk, we configured the elastic load balancer & Auto scaling for the environment. How can i test whether the load balancer & autoscaling is working for my application environment. Any Load testing tools that i can try.

Comment: Remember to scale up slowly as Auto Scaling can take time to respond to increased traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct - you need to load test it.  Be sure to choose a load testing tool that supports elastic load balancing correctly. Specifically, it needs to not cache DNS lookups too long - a mistake which many load testing tools make. Otherwise, the load will continue to be directed to the existing servers even when new servers have been started to respond to increased load.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with beanstalk, but if you're scaling based on CPU usage, it's pretty easy to write a page with some bad code that pegs the CPU.  Add a for loop that loops almost indefinitely in a web page, request the page, and watch the autoscaling do its thing.

Comment: The page with bad code within the app or from somewhere outside.

Comment: the code the misbehaves should be in your app, within the war file that you upload. requesting a specific page would kick it off and hopefully peg the CPU.  if autoscaling is configured to occur based on CPU usage, then your bad code should cause it to cross the threshold and kick off autoscaling.